# jQuery - Append Image to HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Need help.  Want to add an error Image before my text.  It needs to go right before the span with the id of "company"

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">Symbol:
<input type="text" size="7" id="symbol"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
<br/>
<br/><span id="company" class="companyClass"></span>
<br/><span id="price" class="priceClass"></span>
```

JS:

```
var errorUrl = "http://s12.postimg.org/uli5cyrml/error.png"
```

I add my text like so:

`$("#company").text("Webservice Failure! " + "\Contact support");`

Need to add the image right before it.

Comment: try $("#company").html() instead of text(). this way you can add an image inside

Comment: Thanks for all the comments yall..

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#company").before('<img src="somePath" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var errorUrl = "http://s12.postimg.org/uli5cyrml/error.png"
var $img = $('<img />', {src: errorUrl});
$img.insertBefore($("#company"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#company').prepend('<img src=' + errorUrl + ' alt="image" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to add the image before hand to the html, hide it using css, and show it when needed using jquery.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">Symbol:
<input type="text" size="7" id="symbol"></input>
<button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<img id="error-img" src="http://s12.postimg.org/uli5cyrml/error.png"/>
<span id="company" class="companyClass"></span>
<br/><span id="price" class="priceClass"></span>

<style>
    #error-img {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $('#error-img').show();
</script>
```

You can also use jquery instead of css by calling `$('#error-img').hide();` which is equivalent to setting display to none.